# Postfix and Dovecot Sieve spam filter does not work

Tags: spam, dovecot, sieve

CentOS 6.5 x64

I'm trying to apply a Sieve filter to my mailserver (Postfix + Dovecot + Spamassassin) to automatically move spam mails to my Junk folder.

I've added `sieve` to my `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf` protocols.

This is my `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/90-sieve.conf`:

```
plugin {
  sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_global_path = /var/lib/dovecot/sieve/default.sieve
  sieve_after = /var/lib/dovecot/sieve
  sieve_dir = ~/sieve
  sieve_global_dir = /var/lib/dovecot/sieve/
}
```

This is the content of `/var/lib/dovecot/sieve/default.sieve`:

```
require "fileinto";
if header :contains "X-Spam-Flag" "YES" {
  fileinto "Junk";
  stop;
}
```

Which was compiled with `sievec /var/lib/dovecot/sieve/default.sieve`

My Spamassassin works correctly, in fact it adds the [SPAM] string before the subject of the emails and the X-Spam-Flag is set to YES.

I've already restarted dovecot and postfix.

No errors are reported in /var/log/maillog, running `cat /var/log/maillog | grep sieve` does not return anything.

The problem: mails are not moved to Junk folder.

Looks like the sieve filter is not executed at all... How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it upgrading to the newest version of Dovecot from the enterprise repositories.

Comment: I have the same problem more than 2 years later. What version are you running to fix the issue? I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Dovecot 2.2.22 (fe789d2).

Answer (score 0):

- `sieve_global_path` The deprecated name for the `sieve_default` setting (Pigeonhole v0.2 and earlier).
- `sieve_default` (v0.3+) The location of the default personal sieve script file `which gets executed ONLY if user's private Sieve script does no exist`

Check the [multiscript section](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve/Configuration) for instructions on running global Sieve scripts before and after the user's personal script.

Ref: [Dovecot Docs](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve/Configuration)

Comment: I already use sieve_after and no personal sieve scripts are defined.